# subplots with plotly express 4

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I have the following, using plotly express:

```
fig = px.line(series1, x='timestamp', y='data')
fig.show()
```

and it works properly.

I want to make multiple plots together, so I did:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

fig.add_trace(px.line(series1, x='timestamp', y='data'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(px.line(series2, x='timestamp', y='data'), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(px.line(series2, x='timestamp', y='data'), row=2, col=1)

fig.show()
```

but I get:

> Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property of 
>          Invalid elements include: [Figure({
>      'data': [{'hoverlabel': {'namelength': 0},

although,

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=series1['timestamp'], y=series1['data']), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=series2['timestamp'], y=series2['data']), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=series2['timestamp'], y=series2['data']), row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

will work; so it looks like plotly express doesn't work with subplots.

did I miss anything?

additionally, as a bonus question: I haven't found how I can specify the color for each of the traces.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Plotly Express (PX) functions like `px.line()` return figures, just like `make_subplots` does. On the other hand, `add_trace()` accepts trace objects and not figure objects, which is why `fig.add_trace(px.line())` doesn't work.

PX can make subplots using `make_subplots` internally if you pass in the `facet_row` and/or `facet_col` arguments. This means that it is compatible with `make_subplots` in that you can call `add_trace(row=r, col=c)` on a figure created via `px.whatever()`.

In the spirit of StackOverflow, I recommend splitting your "bonus question" into a separate SO question.

Comment: will create a question immediately for the colors

Comment: But if someone wants to add another px.line from another dataset, how can I do it?

Comment: Link that question please?